# WPF XAML ListView - Make TextBlock Text wrap

Tags: wpf, xaml, word-wrap

I have a ListView with ListView.ItemTemplate like this

```
<ListView
    x:Name="myList" 
    BorderBrush="Transparent"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" 
    SelectedIndex="0"
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="5,5,5,5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/> <--THIS WILL FORCE WRAPPING
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FilePath}" 
                               Grid.Row="0" Margin="3,3,3,3" 
                               Style="{StaticResource MyFilePathTextLabel}" 
                               TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>   <-- THIS WILL NOT WRAP TEXT
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3,3,3,3">
                        <TextBlock Text="Lab location: "/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LabLocation}" 
                                   Style="{StaticResource MyLabLocationTextLabel}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    ...
                    ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    ...
    ...
</ListView>
```

This will show ListView items like this:

```
----------------------------------
C:/samples/folderA/myfile1.txt     <-- NO WRAP AS IT FITS
Lab location: Chemistry Lab 301
----------------------------------
C:/samples/folderA/folderB/fold
erC/folderD/folderE/folderF/myf
ile2.txt                           <-- WRAP SINCE NOT FITTING
Lab location: Chemistry Lab 301
----------------------------------
C:/samples/folderA/folderB/myfi
le3.txt                            <-- WRAP SINCE NOT FITTING
Lab location: Chemistry Lab 301
----------------------------------
C:/samples/folderA/folderB/fold
erC/folderD/folderE/folderF/fol
derG/folderH/folderI/folderJ/fo
lderK/myfile4.txt                  <-- WRAP SINCE NOT FITTING
Lab location: Chemistry Lab 301
----------------------------------
C:/samples/myfile5.txt             <-- NO WRAP AS IT FITS
Lab location: Chemistry Lab 301
----------------------------------
```

Above, each item show file location as wrapped if it does not fit the width of the ListView.

**UPDATE:**
Updated XAML

**UPDATE 2:**
Setting the column Width of grid container to hardcoded value of will force wrapping (see above commented line).  But since form is resizable, the grid and ListView is also resizable.  Therefore, I can not hardcode width.  **It needs to wrap according to the current size of the form.**

Comment: I can't understand you requirement. *Do you want* the text to wrap? Because I tested your code and the text is split on more lines as expected.

Comment: @MK87 I have updated XAML.  It does not work in my case.  Much appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the `HorizontalContentAlignement="Stretch"` on the ListView object itself to tell it to stretch it's Content horizontally to fit available space, and set the `HorizontalScrollBarVisiblilty` to Disabled to make sure horizontal scrolling is disabled.

```
<ListView x:Name="myList" ...
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
```

[image]

Comment: You Rock!  ... just as your articles I read do.  This solved the issue.  I have only one problem left as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465077/wpf-xaml-listview-with-scrollbars?noredirect=1#comment62429367_37465077.  Would you mind commenting on that Rachel?  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `Grid` and set `<ColumnDefinition Width="*">`, the `GridColumn` enlarges as much as possible to fill all the available space. Only and only *after* that, other operations like wrapping take place.

In this case, the `GridColumn` becomes large enough to contain all the text on a single line. And that's the reason why the text doesn't wrap: it doesn't need to wrap! It has all the space it needs to stay on a single line!

SOLUTION: Set a fixed column width, as 200, or 100, or anyway try a smaller width, and see the result. At some point the text MUST wrap, with a `GridColumn` thin enough.

**SOLUTION FOR FLEXIBLE WIDTH:**

You have to bind the `Width` of the inner `Grid` (the one with the `RowDefinitions`) to the `ActualWidth` of the outer `Grid` (the one with the `ColumnDefinitions`).

Create a converter like this:

```
public class OuterGridToInnerGridWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((double)value) / 2;
    }
}
```

In this example I suppose that the inner `Grid` has half the `Width` of the outer. If instead you have the column of the `Grid` with `Width="*"` and the second column with a fixed width of - for example - `50`, the converter can be:

```
public class OuterGridToInnerGridWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((double)value) - 50;
    }
}
```

Made this, add this attribute to the inner `Grid`:

```
Width="{Binding ActualWidth,
  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}},
  Converter={StaticResource OuterGridToInnerGridWidthConverter}}"
```

Finally, set `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` for the `ListView`.

This works both when you make the window smaller or bigger: the `TextBlock` resizes and wraps correctly.

Comment: You are correct about that.  I updaed XAML above and added comment.   however, I cannot hardcode width as the form is resizable and all adjusts accordingly.  This is how relative positioning is supposed to work.  So, I cannot use hardcoded width.  Much appreciated

Comment: What happens if you leave `Width="*"` and resize the window to make it smaller? Does the text wrap at a certain point? Or the content stay fixed (with maybe an horizontal scrollbar)?

Comment: No.  If I have Width="*", no wrapping happens at all.  Horizontal scrollbar shows.

Comment: Much appreciated.  Rachel answer solved it but much appreciated MK87

Comment: I've seen, her solution is much simpler and more elegant :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to have the first RowDefinition like :

```
<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
```

instead of

```
<RowDefinition Height="*"/>
```

?

If no success, try temporarily removing  the

```
Style="{StaticResource MyFilePathTextLabel}"
```

also. You did not share its code, so I'm thinking it might break the wrapping.

Comment: Sorry, but that is not working.  Tried both recommendations.  Much appreciated