# Button inside listview c#

Tags: c#, wpf, list, mvvm

I've successfully put a button inside each listview item. But I want to obtain the Item on which the button is.. In this case each item is a Friend and has a button on click of the button I want to now which friend it is. How can I achieve this?

**VIEW**

```
 <ListView x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Friends}" Height="314" BorderThickness="0" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemFriends}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="Resources\Images\ic_status.png" Height="24" Width="18"/>
                    <StackPanel Margin="5" Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding name}"/>                                
                        <StackPanel x:Name="RemoveItems" Margin="5" Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding lastLocation}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding timestamp}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="AdditionItems" Margin="5" Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=loc.area}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=loc.building}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=loc.floor}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=loc.room}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Button Style="{DynamicResource FlatButtonStyle}" Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectViewCommand, ElementName=GeneralWindowView}"  CommandParameter="ChatViewModel"  x:Name="button1" Content="Chat" Margin="10">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Image Source="Resources\Images\chat_image.png"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="AdditionItems" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="RemoveItems" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Best regards,
Antoine

Comment: Can you not pass `Friend` instance instead of `ChatViewModel` string into your command?

Comment: No, because I'm using Rachel model and this CommandParameter is changing viewmodel

Comment: Don't know what _Rachel model_ is but it doesn't change fact that command has only one argument. It can be either your string, your view model or a something else. There's no other way to pass value into command

Comment: Basically I have to pass in the command parameter the name of the ViewModel in order to change the view model. How do you suggest to change to the ChatViewModel and pass it the Friend?

Comment: @Antoine, please can you either check an answer as the correct one, or tell us what are we missing, so we can help you better? This can be useful also to other SO users that see this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this....

```
class Friend
{
    // Other properties......
    public string Link_1 { get; set; }
}
```

set Link_1 = "ChatViewModel" somewhere

XAML

```
<Button x:Name="button1" Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectViewCommand, ElementName=GeneralWindowView}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
```

then in your  SelectViewCommand  Command handler

```
public void OnSelectViewCommand (dynamic obj)
{
    this.Current_ViewModel = this.GetViewModel(obj.Link_1);
}
```

EDIT........

There is another way that directly addresses the issue of sending multiple parameters in the CommandParameter...

XAML

add the manespace

```
xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:CommandParameterExample.Converters"
```

add the  Resource

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Converters:CommandParameter_Converter x:Key="CommandParameter_Converter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Add a hidden Text Block

```
<TextBlock Visibility="Collapsed" Name="VM" Text="ChatViewModel"></TextBlock>
```

Here is your Button

```
<Button Content="Chat" Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectViewCommand, ElementName=GeneralWindowView}" >
    <Button.CommandParameter>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CommandParameter_Converter}">
            <Binding/>
            <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="VM"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```

Here is the  CommandParameter_Converter

```
class CommandParameter_Converter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.Clone(); // simply return an array
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and here is your SelectViewCommand

```
public void OnSelectViewCommand (object parameter)
{
    var values = (object[])parameter;
    var FriendObject = (dynamic)values[0];
    var ViewModelName = (string)values[1];
}
```

This is the correct way to resolve your issue (sending 2 arguments in CommandParameter). But as you can see, it's rather involved....

Comment: Yeah but now your ViewModelName is a property in your Friends class called Link_1, you then use ....CommandParameter="{Binding}" in XAML to pass the entire Friends object (the row the Button is on) to the SelectViewCommand... Now you can use Link_1 property to switch view plus you also have the data from your selected row (Friends object)

Comment: But I have a lot of Models and a lot of places that I change view model using the OnSelectViewCommand I will have to make changes there as well?

Comment: Yep, lol... is only small change Antoine... with WPF\MVVM you'll find yourself refactoring your code quite often. You might start off doing something one way because it fulfils your needs, then your needs change (as in this case) and find that you have to change it. You could simply change it only were you need to, BUT that will leave you code in a mess... doing the SAME thing many different ways is never a good idea....

Comment: In any case you don't have a choice.... the XAML CommandParameter will only take one parameter, ether a string (as you are doing now) or an object, a class that can contain many properties (as above), the ability to call a Command (from the Button) in a different ViewModel means that you can pass something, the CommandParameter (String or Object), from one ViewModel to another....

Comment: And also remember Rachels model was very simple. It was a good example of Navigating between Views but it didn't address your requirements (Passing data + Changing View)... did you ask her for any advice, maybe she has better way, here is the last question she answers 2 days ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465077/wpf-xaml-listview-with-scrollbars/37484974#37484974. I'm sure she wont mind if you ask....

Answer (score 3):

You can bind the `CommandParameter` to the `ListViewItem` to which the `Button` belongs. Something like:

```
<Button x:Name="button1"
        Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectViewCommand,
          ElementName=GeneralWindowView}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}">
```

In this way, the `CommandParameter` is always the `ViewModel` of the `ListViewItem` on which the `Button` stays.

As a side node, I think that if the `SelectViewCommand` deals with the current `ListViewItem`, maybe the `Command` should stay on the `ViewModel` of the `ListViewItem`, not the one on the `GeneralWindowView`...

Any way, hope this helps.

Comment: `CommandParameter="{Binding}"` will do exactly same job. `DataContext` is inherited down the visual tree

Comment: Why on earth the first solution I choose is always the most complicated... Thank you @dkozl, I updated my answer. +1

Comment: I can't change the Command Paramter because I'm using the Rachel example and I'm navigating through this button (changing ViewModel)